# swap element from a map with iter_swap

Tags: c++

I have a "simple" problem :
I'm trying to swap the pairs inside a map to change order.
This code doesn't compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, int> map;
  map.insert({"one", 1});  
  map.insert({"two", 2});  
  map.insert({"three", 3});

  for(const auto& e :map)
  {
    std::cout << e.first << " " << e.second << std::endl;   
  }

  std::iter_swap(map.begin(), map.rbegin());

  for(const auto& e :map)
  {
    std::cout << e.first << " " << e.second << std::endl;   
  }
}
```

Is it possible and how can I do ?

Comment: You can't change the order of an ordered container.  Doing so would break its invariant (being ordered).

Comment: you can use : Boost.Bimap https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html#example4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible

It is not possible. Elements of a map are in the ordering established by the comparison function. The elements cannot be swapped.

If you want a structure where you can choose the order of pairs, you can use `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>` instead. If you want both fast lookup, and arbitrary order, then you want a multi-index data structure. Standard library has no such container. Boost does however.